# Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Unsupported encoding

Tags: java, certificate, rsa, x509, pki

I am getting the below exception when I am trying to transfer the certificate to X.509

> "Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Unsupported
>   encoding"

The 2048 certificate from CA is like this(the certicicate is just one line which has no linefeed) ,is this normal?

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   MIIERTCCAy2gAwIBAgIFIBkicgAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwWTELMAkGA1UEBhMCQ04xMDAuBgNVBAoTJ0NoaW5hIEZpbmFuY2lhbCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uIEF1dGhvcml0eTEYMBYGA1UEAxMPQ0ZDQSBURVNUIE9DQTExMB4XDTE3MDQwNjA2NDQ1OVoXDTE5MDQwNjA2NDQ1OVowdzELMAkGA1UEBhMCQ04xFTATBgNVBAoTDENGQ0EgVEVTVCBDQTERMA8GA1UECxMITG9jYWwgUkExGTAXBgNVBAsTEE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbmFsLTExIzAhBgNVBAMUGjA1MUBDSl9BQUJCQ0BaMDAwMDAwMDU1MUAyMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtgAftvnIcaGITXhuWY1R1IYfrCstmDKJYO9anhFcUrsEe7l1BHcmXeF1Fr7KzTr+XmQx8RkSrECm6Gyfg/jElmh6XHEL3UyExIuSxuCoTs+71JlBPkCDcTdyo4lDI6Ox3JsKU/W8LFKSpae6jAA0uhgwjPCI5uizONLWTdRiXRNRUG7zvGaCgHDipP7gN1Tm+KvlDs8xJGtLdeErlIIDy4Tw2EkK+LD+L9FD8CruzpY52UkTfYfqM3Mwu1EZtfIke0M/dpSkP+46XPJH7CCbXv+f65ST2Uh+PclwPo3O2raZMZ2R3alCEMx0ZKYbA4hekdt/FJygUwN9e1MCu8KqyQIDAQABo4H1MIHyMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFPwLvESaDjGhg6mBhyceBULGv1b4MEgGA1UdIARBMD8wPQYIYIEchu8qAQIwMTAvBggrBgEFBQcCARYjaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jZmNhLmNvbS5jbi91cy91cy0xNS5odG0wOgYDVR0fBDMwMTAvoC2gK4YpaHR0cDovLzIxMC43NC40Mi4zL09DQTExL1JTQS9jcmwxODExOS5jcmwwCwYDVR0PBAQDAgPoMB0GA1UdDgQWBBTNUgad4XedWMDOeezrG+J+iwFxQDAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAgYIKwYBBQUHAwQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAI906RKm5xPIaJzIeVpXRUIyHtf/9klxqNdjoXbwfplSocUioYZDPOy33w2b9Wfl/HDNKVUksv6n09dx0hdwiJZaNaVbLw0VGPwg5eTEcSEj1iQzkGGlsCt8uNROGilB8Vn0cPfhByroFO9e8bj7GNAxYtg7fvUB9XIXlMqLukIZ5JY6yOLj2y/MvoQp7B/9xdBWxqDqWhZaaEgsRxeezZ3CIGQjevSF/xNe8g2zM/13K38h64FGS3P1iNAcyJUfjoMSAXMSgPWE8uPDtENU+XgthSsNrTPBxkkY5ZuEj7YGHsiHt8mAK37QigC12fL1gF7OG8oCE/a1ZyfTukj0KRI=-----END
>   CERTIFICATE-----

The program is like this:

```
  public static X509Certificate getX509Certificate(String base64Cert)
{
    X509Certificate cert = null;
    if (!isNullOrEmpty(base64Cert))
    {
        log.error("getX509Certificate(): " + base64Cert);
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(base64Cert.getBytes()));
        CertificateFactory cf;
        try
        {
            cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is);
        } catch (CertificateException e)
        {
            log.error("cert format error,cert content is [" + base64Cert
                    + "]");
        }
    } else
    {
        log.error("cert is null");
    }
    return cert;
}
```

any help would be appreciated !.

Answer (score 1):

The PEM file format is

- Ignorable data
- A newline, or the beginning of the data buffer
- 5 hyphens
- "BEGIN "
- One or more words (the type info)
- 5 hyphens
- A newline
- Base64-encoded data (the payload)
- A newline
- 5 hyphens
- "END "
- The same value for type info
- 5 hyphens
- Ignorable data

The newlines are a part of the format.  Without it, you're not PEM, and since it presumably only supports PEM and DER (the binary representation of the base64-encoded data), and your value was neither of those, it was in some "unsupported encoding", which happened to be "PEM-like, but without newlines"

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to convert Base64 formatted certificate to X509Certificate

```
    byte[] decodedCertificate = 
    Base64.decodeBase64(encodedCertificate.getBytes());
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory;
    Certificate certificate = null;

    try {
         certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
         certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new 
          ByteArrayInputStream(decodedCertificate));
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      X509Certificate x509Certificate =  (X509Certificate) certificate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway,this is my solution ,transfer the singleline cert to multiline .
but i still don't know the origin reason ,anyone can explain this ,please Post your answer.

```
public static String singleLine2MultiLine(String p10) throws Exception{
    byte[] base64Data = p10.getBytes();
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64Data);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte tmp;
    while ((tmp = (byte) bis.read()) != -1) {
        if (tmp != 0x0a && tmp != 0x0d) {
            bos.write(tmp);
        }
    }
    byte[] bSingleLine = bos.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (int i = 0; i < bSingleLine.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0 && i % 64 == 0) {
            bos2.write("\r\n".getBytes());
        }
        bos2.write(bSingleLine[i]);
        if (i == bSingleLine.length - 1) {
            bos2.write("\r\n".getBytes());
        }
    }
    return new String(bos2.toByteArray());
}
```